# How can I share my stylesheets between different solutions in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three solutions; all share one thing in common which is the stylesheets. I would like to have only one version of the stylesheets.

I thought to put this and maybe other things like common scripts in one project and then have all three solutions reference this same project.

But how can I link in the stylesheets to my layout pages. Currently I use:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Stylesheets/Package3.css")" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify. Do you have 3 distinct solutions or three projects inside a solution? Both cases are interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with your source control?  But the better solution might ultimately be to make a 4th project of your static shared files (ex. css, javascript, images) and deploy them to a URL that you will only use to serve this content.

So you can reference in your project like:

```
<link href="http://mydomain.com/content/stylesheets/package3.css" rel=stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Where `mydomain.com` is actually your 4th project that only hosts the static content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Add as link' option.

Comment: So are you saying I should put the CSS into it's own project. Link in that project to my three solutions and then create a link from the WebUX to the same file in that new project for each solution?

Comment: I think what Max Toro meant was when you use 'Add as link', the css files can be copied to the other projects during the build of the solution (assuming these projects are in the same solution).

Comment: This won't work. OP is for diff solutions. This only work for one solution as I understand it.